# paste column values to another column

Tags: r, dataframe, paste

I have a simple questions that possibly can be solved with `paste` 
My data frame looks like this:

```
x<-c(3,6,7)
y<-c(0.25,0.35,0.62)
dta1<-data.frame(x,y)
  x    y
1 3 0.25
2 6 0.35
3 7 0.62
```

I want to paste these values together in one column.
And add or remove some characters at the same time.
it will looks like this :

```
       x
1 3(.25)
2 6(.35)
3 7(.62)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `paste` or `paste0`, but I find `sprintf` easier to read

```
sprintf("%i(.%i)", dta1$x, round(100*dta1$y))
```

where `%i` marks integer numbers given in the following arguments (`dta1$x` and so on).

Answer (score 3):

You just need to trim the string and combine with `paste`, so something like:

```
paste0(x, "(", substr(y, 2, nchar(y)), ")")
```

will give you what you are after