# R collapsing columns and formatting

Tags: r

Suppose I have a data.frame that looks like this

```
1  5
9  12
34 38
10 40
```

How would I collapse the columns, place a separator in between, and add for instance character "A" to the beginning and "B" to the end so that I would get:

```
A1&5B
A9&12B
A34&38B
A10&40B
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `paste` or `sprintf`. See `?paste`, `?sprintf`.

When you say "a list", do you mean that each element of the list is a string with two numbers (e.g. `x[[1]] = "1 5"`), or do you mean that you have a numeric matrix (e.g. `x[1, ] = c(1, 5)`) or .. ?

```
# e.g. if x is a dataframe
x <- data.frame(A=c(1, 9, 34, 10), B=c(5, 12, 38, 40))
sprintf('A%i&%iB', x$A, x$B)
# or
paste0("A", x$A, "&", x$B, "B") # paste0 has no separator; paste has a " " separator
```

Or supposing you had many columns (not just A and B) and didn't want to type them out manually, this will put a '&' between each value in a row, then paste an "A" on the front and "B" on the back.

```
paste0("A", apply(x, 1, paste, collapse='&'), "B")
```

Essentially this goes along each row (e.g. row one is `c(1, 5)`), then we collapse the contents with '&' in between (`paste(c(1,5), collapse="&"`), and then we paste the A and B on either side of the result (`paste0` as a shorthand for `paste(..., sep="")`).

Comment: You think this is a dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24553339/paste-column-values-to-another-column

Answer (score 1):

```
    df<-data.frame(a=c(1,9,34,10),b=c(5,12,38,40))
    data.frame(name=paste0("A",df$a,"&",df$b,"B"))
```